# Image in URL-encoded Windows Phone 7

Tags: silverlight, image, windows-phone-7

in my windows phone 7 application I have to send a image throught a normal POST method, in which the file's entire binary contents are URL-encoded in silverlight.
I've the image in stream, file e byte[].
How can I do this stuff?

Thx guys

Comment: Since this clearly not actually a good idea some background for the reason why you "have to" send an image this way would be helpful.  I don't like to help people implement things that are on the surface seriously flawed ideas until its clear why it has to be this way.  Are you sure you're not actually supposed to be posting Base64 encoded image in a mime multipart body?

Comment: Hi Anthony, I "have to" post my image in a url-ecoded style because the web server accept two methods for posting image: 1) encode the image in string and send in post "data" paramiter or throught a web-form, but I don't have idea how I can create the web form in a webBrowser control and passing the path of the file without the action of a user... so can you help me in same way? (sorry for my english :P)

Answer (score 0):

Try sending the result of

```
HttpUtility.UrlEncode(System.Text.Encoding.UTF8.GetString(yourByteArray);
```

or similar. You could easily verify using UploadStringAsync.